# Unable to run google maps apiv2

Tags: android, google-maps

I am unable to run google maps api v2 in my tablet. I cant seem to find where the error is. The app crashes as it always stops unexpectedly in the tab. Will someone be able to help me out? I am using FragmentActivity.

Moreover I've cleaned the project and ensure that i imported the google-play-service-lib. I dont understand how i still get errors.

Logcat :

```
01-08 12:54:05.450: E/AndroidRuntime(25497): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-08 12:54:05.450: E/AndroidRuntime(25497): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start     
activity ComponentInfo{com.example.googlemaps/com.example.googlemaps.MainActivity}: 
java.lang.NullPointerException
01-08 12:54:05.450: E/AndroidRuntime(25497):at 
android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2211)
01-08 12:54:05.450: E/AndroidRuntime(25497): at 
android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
01-08 12:54:05.450: E/AndroidRuntime(25497): at 
android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
01-08 12:54:05.450: E/AndroidRuntime(25497):at   
android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
01-08 12:54:05.450: E/AndroidRuntime(25497):at 
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-08 12:54:05.450: E/AndroidRuntime(25497):at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)  
01-08 12:54:05.450: E/AndroidRuntime(25497):at 
android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
01-08 12:54:05.450: E/AndroidRuntime(25497): at 
java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-08 12:54:05.450: E/AndroidRuntime(25497):at 
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
01-08 12:54:05.450: E/AndroidRuntime(25497): at 
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
01-08 12:54:05.450: E/AndroidRuntime(25497): at 
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
01-08 12:54:05.450: E/AndroidRuntime(25497): at 
dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-08 12:54:05.450: E/AndroidRuntime(25497): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-08 12:54:05.450: E/AndroidRuntime(25497): at 
com.example.googlemaps.MainActivity.setUpMap(MainActivity.java:47)
01-08 12:54:05.450: E/AndroidRuntime(25497): at 
com.example.googlemaps.MainActivity.setUpMapIfNeeded(MainActivity.java:33)
01-08 12:54:05.450: E/AndroidRuntime(25497):at 
com.example.googlemaps.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:25)
01-08 12:54:05.450: E/AndroidRuntime(25497): at 
android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133)
01-08 12:54:05.450: E/AndroidRuntime(25497): at 
android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
01-08 12:54:05.450: E/AndroidRuntime(25497): at  
android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2175)
01-08 12:54:05.450: E/AndroidRuntime(25497):    ... 11 more
01-08 12:56:09.040: E/MPL-storeload(440): calData from inv_save_mpl_states, size=2
```

Main:

```
package com.example.googlemaps;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

import android.location.Criteria;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;


public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

private GoogleMap googleMap;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    setUpMapIfNeeded();
}

private void setUpMapIfNeeded() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if (googleMap == null) {
        googleMap = ((SupportMapFragment) 
        getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
        if (googleMap != null) {
            setUpMap();
        }
    }
}

private void setUpMap() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

    LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) 
            getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
    Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
    String provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);
    Location myLocation = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
    googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);
    double latitude = myLocation.getLatitude();
    double longitude = myLocation.getLongitude();

    LatLng latLng = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
    googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
    googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(10));
    googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(latitude, 
            longitude)).title("You are here!"));
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
}
```

Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.googlemaps"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<permission
    android:name="com.example.googlemaps.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<uses-permission android:name="com.example.googlemaps.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />  
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission 
android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="16" />

<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

    <activity
        android:name="com.example.googlemaps.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="AIzaSyC5RVOfXZGfsFHoMosdF_mOOcfaqUZEJJU" />
</application>

</manifest>
```

Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<fragment
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    />

 </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: R u testing on device or emulator?

Comment: in emulator how he will test Google Map V2, it's always ask for update library ........ it's too much hectic process to run Map v2 in emulator.

Comment: @SatyakiMukherjee you can on 4.4. see the second point here http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html

Comment: yes, 4.4 is possible, but for this the user need to update sdk library as well as 4.4 and google play service library.

Comment: @SatyakiMukherjee in any case you should use the updated google play services

Comment: you should also consider checking for the availability of google play services.

Comment: @Raghunandan I know this, but the user who post the question, he needs to do this.

Comment: @SatyakiMukherjee well tell the user or post it as answer. I commented bcoz you  asked "in emulator how he will test Google Map V2,"

Comment: Thank you for your response. And yes i am running it on a tablet. Not an emulator.

Comment: I will need to update my sdk lib and my google-play-service lib as well?

Comment: Will it be possible for me to change the code to set up the map? since there is an error for the Null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager)getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
String provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);
Location myLocation = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
```

In your above code ,

You have created a new object for criteria but no criteria is specified . This might have caused the problem

Try the following code ,

```
LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager)getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES, MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
if (locationManager != null) 
{
     Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
     if (location != null) 
     {
       latitude = location.getLatitude();
       longitude = location.getLongitude();
     }
}
```

Comment: '01-08 16:03:03.390: E/AndroidRuntime(29726): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.googlemaps/com.example.googlemaps.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.googlemaps.MainActivity cannot be cast to android.location.LocationListener'

Comment: add `implements LocationListener` to the Activity .

Comment: will be alright to just change the codes since the issue is about `java.lang.NullPointerException`?

Comment: actually the `NullPointerException` is due to the Criteria you have used . Where have you specified your criteria ? So it is returning null to the string `provider` . When you use it for `getLastKnowLocation` it throws Exception .

Comment: Oh Thank you for the explanation. i couldnt figure out why i was having that error.

Comment: and yes i could use the codes you wrote but `MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES, MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES` are not recognized

Comment: i have been searching for methods to replace null with something else. but to no avail, I'm receiving lots of errors.

Comment: `MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES` is as the name suggests it is the minimum time for updating the location and `MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES` is the minimum distance for updating the location while you move .